# How do I use RSolve to solve the problem below?

Tags: equation-solving, recursion, nonlinear, difference-equations, boundary-conditions

`RSolve` can't compute the solution. Appears that *Mathematica* is having a convergence problem. I don't know if the boundary conditions are properly defined...

```
n = 3;
Alpha = -1.99;
nn = 5;
p = 2;
h = 2;

RSolve[{-((u[t + 2/h] - 2 u[t + 1/h] + u[t])/(1/h^2)) == 
        (1 + (n - 2) (t + 1/h))^(1/(2 - n) (2 (n - 1) + Alpha)) u[t + 1/h]^p, 
       u[0] == 0, (u[10^nn + 1/h] - u[10^nn])/(1/h) == 0}, u[t], t]
```

Comment: Please format your code nicely by clicking the grey "edit" button below your post and using the editing toolbar to format your code in code blocks. For help with that, click the grey question mark on the right side of the toolbar.

Comment: It looks like you are already using `RSolve`. Can you please add information to your post as to what exactly is going wrong? Is it spitting out errors? If so, in what line? Is it just returning the input unevaluated? Etc.

Comment: RSolve, and the usual use of generating functions, usually deals well with problems defining u[t+1] in terms of u[t]. You are using u[t+1], u[t+1/2] and u[t]. I don't think RSolve is going to work. If you could somehow scale your problem perhaps in terms of u[t+2], u[t+1] and u[t] then you might have a chance, but I can't see a way to do that. Another problem you will likely have is having expressions to floating point powers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As remarked by [Bill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18890/bill), `RSolve` requires integer indices.  In addition, it accepts only initial values, not initial and final values.  Making these changes yields,

```
RSolve[{-((u[i + 2] - 2 u[i + 1] + u[i])/(1/h^2)) == 
    (1 + (n - 2) (i + 1/h))^(1/(2 - n) (2 (n - 1) + Alpha)) u[i + 1]^p, 
    u[0] == 0}, u[i], i]
```

Unfortunately, it returns unevaluated.  Perhaps, this is not surprising, because `DSolve` cannot solve the corresponding ODE.  Instead, use `RecurrenceTable` and vary `u[1]` to satisfy the desired final value.  (Note: original version of `s` contained scaling error, which now is corrected.)

```
imax = 10000 h;
s[slp_] := RecurrenceTable[{-((u[i + 2] - 2 u[i + 1] + u[i])/(1/h^2)) == 
    (1 + (n - 2) (i + 1)/h)^(1/(2 - n) (2 (n - 1) + Alpha)) u[i + 1]^p, 
    u[0] == 0, u[1] == slp/h}, u[i], {i, imax}]
sslp = FindRoot[s[slp][[imax]] == s[slp][[imax - 1]], {slp, .0012, .0013}, 
    Evaluated -> False]
(* {slp -> 0.000289931} *)
ListPlot[s[slp /. sslp], DataRange -> imax/h, AxesLabel -> u]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

The recurrence equation above is a finite-difference approximation to an ODE mentioned in comments by the OP on his question [101982](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101982/1063).  That equation can be solved by

```
xf = 10000;
NDSolveValue[{-z''[t] == (1 + (n - 2) t)^(1/(2 - n) (2 (n - 1) + Alpha)) z[t]^p, 
    z[0] == 0, z'[xf] == 0}, z, {t, 0, xf}]
```

The result is indistinguishable to the eye from the plot above.