# Differential equation involving exponents

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

$$\begin{cases}&-z^{\prime\prime}(t)=\lambda(1+(N-2)t)^{\frac1{2-N}(2(N-1)+\alpha)}f(z(t)),\quad t\in(0,+\infty)\\&z(0)=z^\prime(+\infty)=0\end{cases}$$

I tried to solve the equation using the code below, but got a null solution.
If you change the values of p for 2 and alpha to -1.99, a smooth and nonzero solution is obtained. But I need to respect the condition:

> p<=(n+alpha)/(n-2)

. Can anyone help?
Thanks!

```
n = 3;
alpha = 1;
xf = 10000;
p = 3;
s = NDSolve[{-z''[t] == (1 + (n - 2) t)^(1/(2 - n) (2 (n - 1) + alpha)) z[t]^p, 
    z[0] == 0, z'[xf] == 0}, z[t], {t, 0, xf}];
xt = Plot[Evaluate[z[t] /. s], {t, 0, xf}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "got a null solution"? With the code as it is I get a plot without problems.

Comment: A very small number in all the domain.

Comment: And that is not correct?

Comment: I don't belive it is correct. If you look to the boundary conditions you will see that both are not satisfied. And also the solution should looks like a polinomial with higher order than 3.

Comment: Umm, no. z=0 satisfies both z[0]==0 and z'[xf]==0

Comment: I think a good solution should have this behaviour:                                  n = 3;
alpha = -1.99;
xf = 100000;
p = 2;
s = NDSolve[{-z''[
        t] == (1 + (n - 2) t)^(1/(2 - n) (2 (n - 1) + alpha)) z[t]^p, 
     z[0] == 0, z'[xf] == 0}, z[t], {t, 0, xf}] // Chop;
xt = Plot[Evaluate[z[t] /. s], {t, 0, xf}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick]

Comment: @bbgodfrey It doesn't for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6YjTx.png

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries  You are right.  I had reduced `xf`.  With larger values, a non-zero solution is produced.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The desired solution can be obtained, but the computation is temperamental.  Use

```
n = 3;
alpha = 1;
xf = 10000;
p = 3;
s = NDSolveValue[{-z''[t] == (1 + (n - 2) t)^(1/(2 - n) (2 (n - 1) + 1)) z[t]^p, 
    z[0] == 0, z'[xf] == 0}, z, {t, 0, xf}}}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 5]
Plot[s[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {z, t}]
```

[image]

Although the computation is carried to `xf = 10000`, only `0 < t < 10` is plotted to show key behavior near `t = 0`.

**Addendum: More Solutions**

Apparently, there are many solutions to this nonlinear ODE for the parameters given in the question.  For instance, with

```
"StartingInitialConditions" -> {z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 2}
```

[image]

```
"StartingInitialConditions" -> {z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 189/100}
```

[image]

```
"StartingInitialConditions" -> {z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 9/5}
```

[image]

Finding further such solutions becomes progressively more difficult as the number of oscillations increases.  Note also that, for each solution with positive `z'[0]`, a companion solution with negative `z'[0]` exists.  More solutions to this equation are available [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120319/1063).