# Need Help to solve a ordinary differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I need help to find a solution to the differential equation bellow. The solution obtained with this code is a very small negative number in all the domain, and it was mathematically proved that exists a positive solution to this problem. Any hints?

```
solu = NDSolve[{-z''[t] == (Sin[2 + z[t]] z[t]^2)/(1 + t)^4.5,z[0] == 0., z'[10000] == 0.}, z, {t, 0., 10000}, Method -> {"Shooting","StartingInitialConditions" -> {z[0] == 0., z'[0] == 0.15}}]
LogLinearPlot[Chop[Evaluate[z[t] /. solu]], {t, 0.1, 10000}]
```

Comment: Well, the zero function is a solution that satisfies the ODE & BCS.  (It's also, trivially, a polynomial.)

Comment: I cannot see how you can expect to get non-trivial polynomial solutions...

Comment: It seems likely that this nonlinear ODE system has no solution except `z == 0` due to the `Sin[2 + z[t]]` term in the ODE.  Remove it, and solutions can be obtained easily, as in your [earlier question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/120319/1063).

Comment: It was mathematically proved that exists a positive solution to this equation...but what we are obtaining is negative, i dont know why.

Comment: Note that Bob Hanlon's solutions are essentially zero.  The negative values may be due only to rounding error.  Do you get different negative solutions?

Answer (score 3):

```
solu = NDSolve[{-z''[t] == (Sin[2 + z[t]] z[t]^2)/(1 + t)^(9/2), z[0] == 0, 
     z'[10000] == 0}, z, {t, 0, 10000}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", 
      "StartingInitialConditions" -> {z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 15/100}}][[1]];

LogLinearPlot[z[t] /. solu, {t, 0.1, 10000}]
```

[image]

Since the values are so small, Using [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) returns zero ("Chop uses a default tolerance of 10^-10").

With higher precision the values are even smaller

```
solu = NDSolve[{-z''[t] == (Sin[2 + z[t]] z[t]^2)/(1 + t)^(9/2), z[0] == 0, 
     z'[10000] == 0}, z, {t, 0, 10000}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", 
      "StartingInitialConditions" -> {z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 15/100}},
    WorkingPrecision -> 20][[1]];

LogLinearPlot[z[t] /. solu, {t, 1/10, 10000},
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]